# Why wont my data create a table (using BootsrapVue)?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Vue and this is my script:

```js
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
  },
  data(){
    return{
      image: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.divtest()
    this.getTimeTable()
  },
  methods:{
    getTimeTable() {

      var timetable = [{}];
      var stunde = 1
      var calendar = db.collection("mittwoch");
      var wholeDay = calendar.get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          var fullTempTable = doc.data()
          var tmpTable = {
            stunde: stunde,
            fach: fullTempTable.fach,
            lehrer: fullTempTable.lehrer,
            raum: fullTempTable.raum
          };
          stunde++
          timetable.push(tmpTable);

        })
      });
      this.items = timetable;
      this.isLoaded = true;
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm using this template:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" v-if="isLoaded" class="fullscreen background">
    <div class="timetable">
      <b-table striped hover :items="items" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to generate a timetable with some firestore data. I tried to use the example data from the BootstrapVue wiki and it worked just fine, so I think I installed the BootstrapVue module correctly. Furthermore, did I test my code on a vanilla JS website and I got all my data.

Comment: where `timetable` variable comes from in `timetable.push(tmpTable)` ?

Comment: One tip: you may use vue-devtools https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools which would help you analyzing the value of your Vue.js data, in particular `ìtems` in your case.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec So using the Dev tools I found out, that the first object is empty, but how can I fix that?

Comment: What is "the first object"? And have you declared `timetable`, as suggested by Sovalina? Also, do you see any error in the browser console?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I was talking about the first object in the items Array an I have declared the timetable var. I also fixed that in the OP

Comment: try `var timetable = []` not `[{}]`

Comment: @Sovalina I would suggest you write an answer that the OP would accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found my mistake. I had declared the timetable var as followed: [{}]. With the result, that the first object of the array was empty.